# How to create Geoserver scripts?

Tags: geoserver

I need to create some Custom scripts for my Geoserver, I need to be able to capture a WFS Request for some data send it over to another program which pulls data from a database, converts that into a GML/Esri shapefile and returns that to the initial request and displays the gml to them.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on two sites

Comment: I find posting questions on GIS, people don't really respond to code related GIS questions. So I sometimes post it on here if there are no replys

Comment: Pick one or the other,  programming questions are good here but don't first ask on GIS.SE